# ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER Behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-execution-plan

I have a view:

```
create view dbo.vMainTable
as
select MT.* from dbo.Table1 T1 with(index(dbo_Table1_UQ))
inner loop join dbo.MainTable MT with(index(dbo_MainTable_PK)) 
on T1.ID = MT.Table1_ID
go
```

On querying the view, I get the below error if `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` is set to `OFF`.

```
Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and 
without using SET FORCEPLAN.
```

Switching them to `ON` makes the error go away. Is there anything I am missing in this particular view?

EDIT: There are many places where some of our developers have done a `column_name = NULL` instead of `column_name IS NULL`, which would break if I switch these both to `ON`. I was looking for a solution which would take care of this scenario.

Comment: Since the ability to turn `ANSI_NULLS` off is going to be removed in the future, and you know that switching these options `ON` fixes the issue, what actual question are you asking here? Turn them on, be done with it.

Comment: Edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: As I say though, MS are warning that the ability to turn this setting off is going to disappear in a future release. So the correct way to fix this is to fix the code that you **know** will break in a future release of SQL Server.

Comment: Well, you are right. Although this will be a big change, it is the right thing to do.

Comment: Are sure it's just `with(index..)` issue? Did you try removing 'loop' hint? Also, index fields would be helpful. Also, SET ANSI_NULLS OFF can cause additional perfomance issues.

Comment: Yes, I tried that; `loop` does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I undertook the big change of switching `ANSI_NULL` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` to `ON` for all my scripts, and ensured they aren't being turned `OFF` anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `with(index(dbo_Table1_UQ))` and `with(index(dbo_MainTable_PK))` constructs are *hints* (as is anything else you see in a `WITH(...)` )

SQL Server is telling you that if  `ANSI_NULLS` and/or `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` are set to `OFF`, you'll have to remove the `with(index(dbo_Table1_UQ))` and the `with(index(dbo_MainTable_PK))`.

Hints are not usually necessary to a query/view, and are inserted to optimize the performance of the query.  You may well find improved performance by omitting them, but this must be assessed on a case by case basis.  If you test the query in SSMS and show the execution plan and query performance, you can assess for yourself if these `WITH()` statements are necessary.

Comment: I realized that. But unfortunately, removing them is not an option.